# Adding declarations file manually (TypeScript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, google-sheets

I didn't find a declaration file for 'google-spreadsheet' so I'm trying to create one by myself:

in typings -> modules, I've added a new folder named "google-spreadsheet", and there I've added a new file named "index.d.ts" which has the following content:

```
export class GoogleSpreadsheet {

}
```

In the client file I have this:

```
import * as GoogleSpreadsheet from 'google-spreadsheet';
```

But 'google-spreadsheet' is marked with red, saying:

> TS2307 Cannot find module 'google-spreadsheet'.

BTW I've NPM-installed 'google-spreadsheet' and it works JavaScriptly. Only the TypeScript bothers me here.

Any ideas how to solve that?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you dont need to care about the typings inside this module you can only create a `*.d.ts` file and put the following content (e.g. create a typings.d.ts):

```
declare module 'google-spreadsheet';
```

To define the types inside the module you can change the above code to:

```
declare module 'google-spreadsheet' {
    // define the types...
}
```

Comment: Where do you put the .d.ts file? TS doesn't seem to find it, no matter where I put it.

Comment: I created `@types/<module_name>` dir in my `src` and put there `index.d.ts` file with one line like above. It worked.

Answer (score 25):

From the root of your project:

1. `mkdir -p src/@types/google-spreadsheet` - create a folder for your module's type declarations.
2. `echo "declare module 'google-spreadsheet';" > src/@types/google-spreadsheet/index.d.ts`

Also, ensure your `tsconfig` is configured to include the `@types` folders using [the typeRoots option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#typeRoots).

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": ["src/@types", "node_modules/@types"]
  }
}
```

Also, you might want to take a look at the [documentation on declaration files](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/library-structures.html).

Comment: Federico Are there any advantages to using this approach over the *.d.ts approach? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I´ve ran into this problem while developing PowerBI custom visuals with echarts.
Just creating the .d.ts file didnt helped. I had to make an include statement inside the tsconfig.json which pointed to the root (where my .d.ts file is located with the declare mdoule statement)

externals.d.ts ->

declare module 'XXX/XXX'

---

tsconfig.json ->

"include": ["./"]

Comment: This solved it for me. I have a `@types` in my root folder where I put my own definition files. `"include": ["@types/**/*.d.ts"]` made typescript find all my custom typings.

Comment: I am so happy, I think this is the first time I helped someone on stack :)