# Adding watermark.js to angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular

Hi I am trying to add watermark to the image and i am trying to include watermark.js to the angular 4. Could someone please tell me how to include watermark.js in angular. I tried installing using

> npm install watermark -save

and then using the

> import * as watermark from 'watermark';

but the above line throws me an error stating cannot find module 'watermark' 
can someone please tell how i can import the watermark.js and use it to watermark my image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing type definitions for watermark.js. However, [judging by this github issue](https://github.com/brianium/watermarkjs/issues/38), the authors of this lib currently don't offer them.

You have a couple of possibilities to fix this:

- [Declare type definition manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42964013/adding-declarations-file-manually-typescript). This is the quickest way, but you'll also lose all type safety when it comes to using this lib
- Help with creating proper type definitions (as shown in [this tutorial](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html)). This way you'll be type safe, learn a lot about the TS type system, and, as a bonus, contribute back to the OSS community.

Good luck!